# What is Pointer size in Tables?

Tags: mysql, database, pointers, myisam

As written somewhere -

> MyISAM tables created in MySQL with variable-length rows are
>   configured
>         by default to handle 256TB of data, using 6-byte pointers to the data
>         records. Earlier MySQL versions defaulted to 4-byte pointers for up to 4GB of data.

What do they mean by **6-byte or 4-byte pointer**  and what **reference** the pointer holds.Explain?

Answer (score 1):

The pointers are positions in the file that holds the database data. When the schema for a table includes variable-length columns (e.g. `VARCHAR` strings), the data for a row is not necessarily in a contiguous block in the file that holds the table. When a row is updated, it may not fit in its old space because a column has grown. In this case, the row is split up; as many columns as can fit in the old space is stored there, while the excess is stored in newly allocated space in the file.

This requires it to have pointers between different parts of the file, to indicate where each part of the row is. These pointers are now 6 bytes.

Comment: okay but what defines the size of Pointer as in this case it is 6-bytes.thanks

Comment: It's defined by how it stores these file offsets in the data structures in the database.

Answer (score 1):

See the VARIABLE `myisam_data_pointer_size`.

@Barmar provided only part of the story.  The "pointers" are also used for indexes.  An index (in the `.MYI` file), even a `PRIMARY KEY`, 'points' into the data (`.MYD`).  It points to the beginning of the data record.  (From there, the record may, or many not, be fragmented as Barmer discusses.)

In the early days, the variable *defaulted* to 4 bytes.  This lead to the *myth* that MySQL tables were limited to 4GB (the max that a 4-byte pointer can resolve to).  The current default for `myisam_data_pointer_size` is 6, leading to the huge 256TB limit.  The max is 7, leading to an even bigger limit.

This pointer limit applies to `DYNAMIC` MyISAM schemas.  For `FIXED` (no `VARCHAR`, no `TEXT`, etc), there is another setting.  (I forget the name.)  I think it's default value is 1 less.  So, using the default limits a `FIXED` table to 1T *rows* (of whatever `FIXED` size they are).  With `FIXED`, the fragmentation does not exist, and the 'pointers' are "row numbers" not "byte offsets".

[My 'Limits' blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits).

TMI?